# Rails using plural table names even though I told it to use singular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I tried to run `rake test:profile` and I got this error:

```
... Table 'mcif2.accounts' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM `accounts`
```

I know `accounts` doesn't exist. It's called `account`.

I know Rails uses plural table names by default but here's what my `config/environment.rb` looks like:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
McifRails::Application.initialize!

ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false
```

And here's what `db/schema.rb` looks like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 0) do

  create_table "account", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer   "customer_id",              :limit => 8,                                         :null => false
    t.string    "account_number",                                                                :null => false
    t.integer   "account_type_id",          :limit => 8
    t.date      "open_date",                                                                     :null => false
```

So I don't understand why Rails still wants to call it `accounts` sometimes. Any ideas?

If it helps give any clues at all, [here](http://pastebin.com/Y9P3Cakr) are the results of `grep -ir 'accounts' *`.

Comment: What Rails version are you using? Ate you generating relevant files with Rails generate script or creating them manually?

Comment: 3.0.3. No, I'm using `rake db:schema:dump`.

Comment: The error message isn't quite clear. Could you look at the log to see which SQL statement is causing the error?

Comment: The SQL statement is simply `DELETE FROM accounts`.

Comment: D'oh! Sometimes I'm just blind!

Comment: It happens to the best of us. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you've named your fixture `accounts.yml` or used the directive `fixtures :accounts` in one of the performance test. Rails fill the related table using the fixture name without knowledge about the model.

Comment: No, I don't have any file called `accounts.rb`.

Comment: And what is the content of the performance tests? Are their `fixtures` directive using the plural form?

Comment: Aha! Your answer was pretty much right. The reason I didn't pick up on it right away if because my fixture file was called `accounts.yml` instead of `accounts.rb`. Changing that filename to `account.yml` fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, I meant to write `accounts.yml`, that was a typo!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set in your model

```
set_table_name "account"
```

Comment: This is deprecated now - Use self.table_name = 'account' in your Account model.